# Multiplication in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multiplication

I'm trying to make a program that generates 2 random numbers, then, after the user inputs the multiplication of those numbers, it will tell the user in a MessageBox whether or not the user was right or wrong. Sort of like an educational simulator.

I'm having problems with the end part. What I'm saying is; If the answer is the same as number1 and number2 multiplied, then it says; "Rétt!" and if not; "Rangt..."

Any ideas?

```
    private void bt_end_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int number1 = 0;
        int number2 = 0;
        int answer = 0;
        tbnumber1.Text = number1.ToString();
        tbnumber2.Text = number2.ToString();

        if (svar == (number1 * number2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rétt!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rangt...");
        }
    }
}
```

}

The full code.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int tala1 = 0;
    int tala2 = 0;
    int svar = 0;

    private void btstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbtala1.Text = "";
        tbtala2.Text = "";
        tbsvar.Text = "";

        Random random = new Random();

        tala1 = random.Next(1, 11);
        tala2 = random.Next(1, 11);

        tbtala1.Text = tala1.ToString();
        tbtala2.Text = tala2.ToString();
    }

    private void btend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbtala1.Text = tala1.ToString();
        tbtala2.Text = tala2.ToString();
        tbsvar.Text = svar.ToString();

        if (svar == (tala1 * tala2).ToString())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rétt!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rangt... :(");
        }
    }
}
```

}

SOLVED. Thank you to everyone who did/tried to help.

Final Version:
Final Version:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int tala1 = 0;
    int tala2 = 0;
    int svar = 0;

    private void btstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbtala1.Text = "";
        tbtala2.Text = "";
        tbsvar.Text = "";

        Random random = new Random();

        tala1 = random.Next(1, 11);
        tala2 = random.Next(1, 11);

        tbtala1.Text = tala1.ToString();
        tbtala2.Text = tala2.ToString();
    }

    private void btend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tala1 = Convert.ToInt32(tbtala1.Text);
        tala2 = Convert.ToInt32(tbtala2.Text);
        svar = Convert.ToInt32(tbsvar.Text);

        if (svar == (tala1 * tala2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rétt!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rangt... :(");
        }
```

Comment: Your code is completely wrong. You never define `svar` and you set tbnumber1 and tbnumber2 to 0 but you never read anything into number1 and number2, so those variables are always 0.

Comment: I suggest you try debugging this and see what contents are in number1, number2 and answer (and svar)

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error message, the code isn't WRONG, it's just not giving the results I want. Every time I put in the right code, the wrong messagebox appears. It always comes up as "Rangt..."

Comment: what is svar exactly?

Comment: If the code isnt giving the results you want, then by definition it is wrong

Comment: Is svar supposed to be 0 * 0? Because that's what you're doing. You never set number1 and number2 to anything other than 0, so any time svar is something other than 0, you will get Rangt...

Comment: Tobberoth, I think I solved this, look at my full code in the edited post and tell me if it's still like that. I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the numbers in the textbox values. you have to convert textbox values to numbers.

```
private void btend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try{
        tala1 = Convert.ToInt32(tbtala1.Text);
        tala2 = Convert.ToInt32(tbtala2.Text);
        svar = Convert.ToInt32(tbsvar.Text);

        if (svar == (tala1 * tala2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rétt!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rangt... :(");
        }
    }catch{
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand what I did wrong there. Newbie mistake, thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a safe manner, you should not only `Parse` the text inputs to numbers, but you should also ensure that the text does in fact contain numbers first. If your numbers are supposed to be integers then you could use this:

```
private void bt_end_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(tbnumber1.Text, out number1) || 
        int.TryParse(tbnumber12.Text, out number2)) MessageBox.Show("Rangt...");

    MessageBox.Show(svar == number1 * number2 ? "Rétt!" : "Rangt...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.I observed that you have not initialized variable 'svar' anywhere.**

Initialise your svar variable with proper value.

**2.Replace This :**

```
  if (svar == (number1 * number2).ToString())
```

**With Following :**

```
   if (svar == (number1 * number2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You never define svar. You probably meant something like this, assuming svar was set earlier and is the correct product of the random multiplication:

```
private void bt_end_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;

    number1 = int.Parse(tbnumber1.Text);
    number2 = int.Parse(tbnumber2.Text);

    if (svar == (number1 * number2))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Rétt!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Rangt...");
    }
}
```